# in php how to delete text line in txt / notepad file when txt reaches 100 lines

Tags: php

How to delete / clear lines of data if it reaches 100th line. I checked some examples, but it is not working.

I need to check the number of the line end if it reaches line number 100, delete or clear all in that text file.

The following code is taken from an example, but this is also not working:

```
<?php
    $text = "log.txt";
    $lines = explode("\n", $text);

    $lines = array_slice($lines, 0, 10); //10 is how many lines you want to keep
    $text = implode("\n", $lines);
?>
```

Comment: Not to sure, but you want to read a file and if it is bigger than 100 lines you want to delete all lines otherwise not?

Comment: @JoelHinz please clean up the entire question instead of making such a minor edit.

Comment: `delete or clear` -> You mean to delete the file or delete all lines ?

Comment: @mahesh I have edited in the proper php open tag. Do you have that in your code? Also what is not working? What does it do? What is it supposed to do? What does it do instead? Have you debugged your code? What was the result?

Comment: @Rizier123 can you provide example for read and delete

Comment: @ Sulthan Allaudeen  delete the lines

Comment: @mahesh So ^ did I guessed correct with my guess?

Comment: @PeeHaa duly noted, will stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this: you will need to take it and fit it to your application, but I think this is what you are looking for.

```
//Count lines
$file="largefile.txt";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle);
  $linecount++;
}

fclose($handle);

//Remove lines
if ($linecount ==100)
{
$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$remove = "balblalbllablab";
foreach($lines as $key => $line)
  if(stristr($line, $remove)) unset($lines[$key]);

$data = implode('\n', array_values($lines));

$file = fopen($path);
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);

}
```